# Building a form for rebooting many network devices

Tags: python, performance, form, flask

I have several IP based devices that, due to building maintenance, occasionally lose their communication with the other devices. Normally you'd have to find the device IP, go to its control page and click the 3 buttons to reboot it. I have built an app that lists the devices and separate them by building and type (Encoder/Decoder or Net Relay). Once you submit the form it begins rebooting them. This works but is REALLY slow. I suspect that it is the way I'm building the list of devices to reboot. What is the best way to parse a large form and skip the sections with no data returned?

Here is the whole code:

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for
import requests
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import widgets, SelectMultipleField


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "**************"

#: Set Choices For Each Building //

B100_Enc_Dec = [('10.203.81.151', '608 Decoder'), ('10.203.81.152', '601 Decoder'), ('10.203.81.153', 'ALC1 Decoder'),
                ('10.203.81.154', 'ALC2 Decoder'), ('10.203.81.155', 'ALC3 Decoder')]
B100_Net = [('10.203.81.156', 'Net Relay 1'), ('10.203.81.157', 'Net Relay 2'), ('10.203.81.158', 'Net Relay 3')]
B200_Enc_Dec = [('10.202.91.220', 'ALC1 Encoder'), ('10.202.91.221', 'ALC2 Encoder'), ('10.202.91.222', 'ALC3 Encoder')]
B200_Net = [('10.202.91.223', 'ALC1 Net Relay 1')]
B201N_Enc_Dec = [('10.202.94.225', '608 Decoder'), ('10.202.94.226', '601 Decoder'), ('10.202.94.227', 'ALC1 Decoder')]
B201N_Net = [('10.202.94.228', 'Net Relay 1'), ('10.202.94.229', 'Net Relay 2')]
B201S_Enc_Dec = [('10.202.95.216', '608 Decoder'), ('10.202.95.217', '601 Decoder'), ('10.202.95.218', 'ALC1 Decoder')]
B201S_Net = [('10.202.95.219', 'Net Relay 1'), ('10.202.95.220', 'Net Relay 2')]
B400_Enc_Dec = [('10.202.145.214', '608 Decoder'), ('10.202.145.215', '601 Decoder'), ('10.202.145.216', 'ALC1 Decoder'),
                ('10.202.145.217', 'ALC2 Decoder'), ('10.202.145.218', 'ALC3 Decoder'),
                ('10.202.142.238', '400A Encoder')]
B400_Net = [('10.202.145.220', 'Net Relay 1'), ('10.202.145.221', 'Net Relay 2'), ('10.202.142.239', '400A Net Relay 1')]
B400A_Enc_Dec = [('10.203.168.226', '608 Decoder'), ('10.203.168.227', '601 Decoder'), ('10.203.168.228', 'ALC1 Decoder'),
                 ('10.203.168.229', 'ALC2 Decoder'), ('10.203.168.230', 'ALC3 Decoder')]
B400A_Net = [('10.203.168.231', 'Net Relay 1'), ('10.203.168.232', 'Net Relay 2')]
B501_Enc_Dec = [('10.203.233.184', '608 Decoder'), ('10.203.233.185', '601 Decoder')]
B501_Net = [('10.203.233.186', 'Net Relay 1')]
B601_Enc_Dec = [('10.202.20.154', '601 Encoder'),  ('10.202.20.156', '608 Decoder')]
B601_Net = [('10.202.20.155', 'Net Relay 1')]
B602_Enc_Dec = [('10.203.235.227', '608 Decoder'), ('10.203.235.223', '601 Decoder')]
B602_Net = [('10.203.235.224', 'Net Relay 1')]
B603_Enc_Dec = [('10.203.230.209', '608 Decoder'), ('10.203.230.210', '601 Decoder')]
B603_Net = [('10.203.230.211', 'Net Relay 1')]
B606_Enc_Dec = [('10.203.224.216', '608 Decoder'), ('10.203.224.217', '601 Decoder')]
B606_Net = [('10.203.224.218', 'Net Relay 1')]
B608_Enc_Dec = [('10.202.175.232', '608 Encoder')]
B608_Net = [('10.202.175.233', 'Net Relay 1'), ('10.202.175.234', 'Net Relay 2'), ('10.202.175.235', 'Net Relay 3'),
            ('10.202.175.236', 'Net Relay 4'), ('10.202.175.237', 'Net Relay 5')]
B611_Enc_Dec = [('10.203.220.233', '608 Decoder'), ('10.203.220.234', '601 Decoder')]
B611_Net = [('10.203.220.235', 'Net Relay 1')]
B800_Enc_Dec = [('10.202.230.155', '608 Decoder'), ('10.202.230.181', '601 Decoder'), ('10.202.230.157', 'ALC1 Decoder'),
                ('10.202.230.158', 'ALC2 Decoder'), ('10.202.230.159', 'ALC3 Decoder')]
B800_Net = [('10.202.230.160', 'Net Relay 1'), ('10.202.230.161', 'Net Relay 2')]
B2000S_Enc_Dec = [('10.202.171.224', '608 Decoder'), ('10.202.171.225', '601 Decoder'), ('10.202.171.226', 'ALC1 Decoder'),
                 ('ALC2 IP', 'ALC2 Decoder (No IP)'), ('ALC3 IP', 'ALC3 Decoder (No IP)')]
B2000S_Net = [('10.202.171.227', 'Net relay 1'), ('10.202.171.228', 'Net Relay 2')]
B2000N_Enc_Dec = [('10.202.171.218', '608 Decoder'), ('10.202.171.219', '601 Decoder'), ('10.202.171.220', 'ALC1 Decoder'),
                  ('10.202.171.221', 'ALC2 Decoder')]
B2000N_Net = [('10.202.171.222', 'Net Relay 1'), ('10.202.171.223', 'Net Relay 2')]
B2kA_Enc_Dec = [('10.202.179.218', '608 Decoder'), ('10.202.179.219', '601 Decoder'), ('10.202.179.220', 'ALC1 Decoder'),
                ('10.202.179.221', 'ALC2 Decoder'), ('10.202.179.222', 'ALC3 Decoder')]
B2kA_Net = [('10.202.179.223', 'Net Relay 1'), ('10.202.179.224', 'Net Relay 2')]
B3000ASL_Enc_Dec = [('10.203.190.216', '608 Decoder'), ('10.203.190.217', '601 Decoder'), ('10.203.190.218', 'ALC3 Decoder')]
B3000ASL_Net = [('10.203.190.220', 'Net Relay 1'), ('10.203.190.221', 'Net Relay 2')]
B3000ANL_Enc_Dec = [('10.203.192.227', '608 Decoder'), ('10.203.192.228', '601 Decoder'), ('10.203.192.229', 'ALC3 Decoder')]
B3000ANL_Net = [('10.203.192.231', 'Net Relay 1'), ('10.203.192.232', 'Net Relay 2')]
Childcare_Enc_Dec = [('10.202.214.186', '608 Decoder'), ('10.202.214.187', '601 Decoder')]
Childcare_Net = [('10.202.214.188', 'Net Relay 1')]
TMS_Enc_Dec = [('10.202.214.191', '608 Decoder'), ('10.202.214.192', '601 Decoder')]
TMS_Net = [('10.202.214.193', 'Net Relay 1')]
Fit_Enc_Dec = [('10.202.214.196', '608 Decoder'), ('10.202.214.197', '601 Decoder')]
Fit_Net = [('10.202.214.198', 'Net Relay 1')]


class RebootForm(FlaskForm):
    B100_Enc_Dec = SelectMultipleField('Building 100 Encoders / Decoders', choices=B100_Enc_Dec,
                                       option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                       widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    B100_Net = SelectMultipleField('Building 100 Net Relays', choices=B100_Net,
                                   option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                   widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    B200_Enc_Dec = SelectMultipleField('Building 200 Encoders / Decoders', choices=B200_Enc_Dec,
                                       option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                       widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    B200_Net = SelectMultipleField('Building 200 Net Relays', choices=B200_Net,
                                   option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                   widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    B201N_Enc_Dec = SelectMultipleField('Building 201 N Encoders / Decoders', choices=B201N_Enc_Dec,
                                        option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                        widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    B201N_Net = SelectMultipleField('Building 201 Net Relays', choices=B201N_Net,
                                    option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                    widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    B201S_Enc_Dec = SelectMultipleField('Building 201 S Encoders / Decoders', choices=B201S_Enc_Dec,
                                        option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                        widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    B201S_Net = SelectMultipleField('Building 201 S Net Relays', choices=B201S_Net,
                                    option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                    widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    B400_Enc_Dec = SelectMultipleField('Building 400 Encoders / Decoders', choices=B400_Enc_Dec,
                                       option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                       widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    B400_Net = SelectMultipleField('Building 400 Net Relays', choices=B400_Net,
                                   option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                   widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    B400A_Enc_Dec = SelectMultipleField('Building 400 Add. Encoders / Decoders', choices=B400A_Enc_Dec,
                                        option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                        widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    B400A_Net = SelectMultipleField('Building 400 Add. Net Relays', choices=B400A_Net,
                                    option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                    widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    B501_Enc_Dec = SelectMultipleField('Building 501 Encoders / Decoders', choices=B501_Enc_Dec,
                                       option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                       widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    B501_Net = SelectMultipleField('Building 501 Net Relays', choices=B501_Net,
                                   option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                   widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    B601_Enc_Dec = SelectMultipleField('Building 601 Encoders / Decoders', choices=B601_Enc_Dec,
                                       option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                       widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    B601_Net = SelectMultipleField('Building 601 Net Relays', choices=B601_Net,
                                   option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                   widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    B602_Enc_Dec = SelectMultipleField('Building 602 Encoders / Decoders', choices=B602_Enc_Dec,
                                       option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                       widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    B602_Net = SelectMultipleField('Building 602 Net Relays', choices=B602_Net,
                                   option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                   widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    B603_Enc_Dec = SelectMultipleField('Building 603 Encoders / Decoders', choices=B603_Enc_Dec,
                                       option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                       widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    B603_Net = SelectMultipleField('Building 603 Net Relays', choices=B603_Net,
                                   option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                   widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    B606_Enc_Dec = SelectMultipleField('Building 606 Encoders / Decoders', choices=B606_Enc_Dec,
                                       option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                       widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    B606_Net = SelectMultipleField('Building 606 Net Relays', choices=B606_Net,
                                   option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                   widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    B608_Enc_Dec = SelectMultipleField('Building 608 Encoders / Decoders', choices=B608_Enc_Dec,
                                       option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                       widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    B608_Net = SelectMultipleField('Building 608 Net Relays', choices=B608_Net,
                                   option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                   widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    B611_Enc_Dec = SelectMultipleField('Building 611 Encoders / Decoders', choices=B611_Enc_Dec,
                                       option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                       widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    B611_Net = SelectMultipleField('Building 611 Net Relays', choices=B611_Net,
                                   option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                   widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    B800_Enc_Dec = SelectMultipleField('Building 800 Encoders / Decoders', choices=B800_Enc_Dec,
                                       option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                       widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    B800_Net = SelectMultipleField('Building 800 Net Relays', choices=B800_Net,
                                   option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                   widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    B2000S_Enc_Dec = SelectMultipleField('Building 2000 S Encoders / Decoders', choices=B2000S_Enc_Dec,
                                         option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                         widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    B2000S_Net = SelectMultipleField('Building 2000 S Net Relays', choices=B2000S_Net,
                                     option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                     widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    B2000N_Enc_Dec = SelectMultipleField('Building 2000 N Encoders / Decoders', choices=B2000N_Enc_Dec,
                                         option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                         widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    B2000N_Net = SelectMultipleField('Building 2000 N Net Relays', choices=B2000N_Net,
                                     option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                     widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    B2kA_Enc_Dec = SelectMultipleField('Building 2000 Add. Encoders / Decoders', choices=B2kA_Enc_Dec,
                                       option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                       widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    B2kA_Net = SelectMultipleField('Building 2000 Add. Net Relays', choices=B2kA_Net,
                                   option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                   widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    B3000ASL_Enc_Dec = SelectMultipleField('Building 3000 A-S Lexus Encoders /Decoders', choices=B3000ASL_Enc_Dec,
                                           option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                           widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    B3000ASL_Net = SelectMultipleField('Building 3000 A-S Lexus Net Relays', choices=B3000ASL_Net,
                                       option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                       widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    B3000ANL_Enc_Dec = SelectMultipleField('Building 3000 A-N Lexus', choices=B3000ANL_Enc_Dec,
                                           option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                           widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    B3000ANL_Net = SelectMultipleField('Building 3000 A-N Lexus', choices=B3000ANL_Net,
                                       option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                       widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    Childcare_Enc_Dec = SelectMultipleField('Childcare Encoders / Decoders', choices=Childcare_Enc_Dec,
                                            option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                            widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    Childcare_Net = SelectMultipleField('Childcare Net relays', choices=Childcare_Net,
                                        option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                        widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    TMS_Enc_Dec = SelectMultipleField('Team Member Services Encoders / Decoders', choices=TMS_Enc_Dec,
                                      option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                      widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    TMS_Net = SelectMultipleField('Team Member Services Net Relays', choices=TMS_Net,
                                  option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                  widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    Fit_Enc_Dec = SelectMultipleField('Fitness Center Encoders / Decoders', choices=Fit_Enc_Dec,
                                      option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                      widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))
    Fit_Net = SelectMultipleField('Fitness Center Net Relays', choices=Fit_Net,
                                  option_widget=widgets.CheckboxInput(),
                                  widget=widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False))


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/form', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def form():
    form = RebootForm()
    ugly_messages = []
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        ip_addresses = (form.B100_Enc_Dec.data + form.B200_Enc_Dec.data + form.B201N_Enc_Dec.data + form.B201S_Enc_Dec.data +
                        form.B400_Enc_Dec.data + form.B400A_Enc_Dec.data + form.B501_Enc_Dec.data + form.B601_Enc_Dec.data +
                        form.B602_Enc_Dec.data + form.B603_Enc_Dec.data + form.B606_Enc_Dec.data +
                        form.B608_Enc_Dec.data + form.B611_Enc_Dec.data + form.B800_Enc_Dec.data +
                        form.B2000S_Enc_Dec.data + form.B2000N_Enc_Dec.data + form.B2kA_Enc_Dec.data +
                        form.B3000ANL_Enc_Dec.data + form.B3000ASL_Enc_Dec.data + form.Childcare_Enc_Dec.data +
                        form.TMS_Enc_Dec.data + form.Fit_Enc_Dec.data)
        for ip_address in ip_addresses:
            try:
                requests.get('http://{}/rc.cgi?L=uirreboot.html&c=99'.format(ip_address))
                ugly_messages.append('rebooting {}'.format(ip_address))
                ugly_messages.append('Please wait 30 secs.')
            except Exception:
                ugly_messages.append('{} did not reboot. It may be offline.'.format(ip_address))
        ip_addresses_nr = (form.B100_Net.data + form.B200_Net.data + form.B201N_Net.data + form.B201S_Net.data +
                           form.B400_Net.data + form.B400A_Net.data + form.B501_Net.data + form.B601_Net.data +
                           form.B602_Net.data + form.B603_Net.data + form.B606_Net.data + form.B608_Net.data +
                           form.B611_Net.data + form.B800_Net.data + form.B2000S_Net.data + form.B2000N_Net.data +
                           form.B2kA_Net.data + form.B3000ANL_Net.data + form.B3000ASL_Net.data +
                           form.Childcare_Net.data + form.TMS_Net.data + form.Fit_Net.data)
        for ip_address_nr in ip_addresses_nr:
            try:
                requests.get('http://{}/setup.cgi?L=uireboot2.html&R'.format(ip_address_nr))
                ugly_messages.append('rebooting {}'.format(ip_address_nr))
                ugly_messages.append('Please wait 30 secs.')
            except Exception:
                ugly_messages.append('{} did not reboot. It may be offline.'.format(ip_address_nr))
        return "<br/>".join(ugly_messages)
    return render_template('form.html', form=form)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I think that where I concatenate the lists together it takes a while to loop through it all.

**Problem Area?**

```
@app.route('/form', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def form():
    form = RebootForm()
    ugly_messages = []
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        ip_addresses = (form.B100_Enc_Dec.data + form.B200_Enc_Dec.data + form.B201N_Enc_Dec.data + form.B201S_Enc_Dec.data +
                        form.B400_Enc_Dec.data + form.B400A_Enc_Dec.data + form.B501_Enc_Dec.data + form.B601_Enc_Dec.data +
                        form.B602_Enc_Dec.data + form.B603_Enc_Dec.data + form.B606_Enc_Dec.data +
                        form.B608_Enc_Dec.data + form.B611_Enc_Dec.data + form.B800_Enc_Dec.data +
                        form.B2000S_Enc_Dec.data + form.B2000N_Enc_Dec.data + form.B2kA_Enc_Dec.data +
                        form.B3000ANL_Enc_Dec.data + form.B3000ASL_Enc_Dec.data + form.Childcare_Enc_Dec.data +
                        form.TMS_Enc_Dec.data + form.Fit_Enc_Dec.data)
        for ip_address in ip_addresses:
            try:
                requests.get('http://{}/rc.cgi?L=uirreboot.html&c=99'.format(ip_address))
                ugly_messages.append('rebooting {}'.format(ip_address))
                ugly_messages.append('Please wait 30 secs.')
            except Exception:
                ugly_messages.append('{} did not reboot. It may be offline.'.format(ip_address))
        ip_addresses_nr = (form.B100_Net.data + form.B200_Net.data + form.B201N_Net.data + form.B201S_Net.data +
                           form.B400_Net.data + form.B400A_Net.data + form.B501_Net.data + form.B601_Net.data +
                           form.B602_Net.data + form.B603_Net.data + form.B606_Net.data + form.B608_Net.data +
                           form.B611_Net.data + form.B800_Net.data + form.B2000S_Net.data + form.B2000N_Net.data +
                           form.B2kA_Net.data + form.B3000ANL_Net.data + form.B3000ASL_Net.data +
                           form.Childcare_Net.data + form.TMS_Net.data + form.Fit_Net.data)
        for ip_address_nr in ip_addresses_nr:
            try:
                requests.get('http://{}/setup.cgi?L=uireboot2.html&R'.format(ip_address_nr))
                ugly_messages.append('rebooting {}'.format(ip_address_nr))
                ugly_messages.append('Please wait 30 secs.')
            except Exception:
                ugly_messages.append('{} did not reboot. It may be offline.'.format(ip_address_nr))
        return "<br/>".join(ugly_messages)
    return render_template('form.html', form=form)
```

What is the best way to combat the slowness? Is there a way to skip sections that don't have their checkbox checked and build the list to reboot out of the rest?

Comment: Please never, EVER post keys or passwords in your code. I've taken the liberty of removing it for you.

Comment: @Reinderien that was a fake key where I smashed the keyboard, but thanks lol.